# Track bounced/undeliverable emails sent by AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm looking for a way to figure out if the emails AWS Cognito sends out (e.g. verification emails, password reset emails, etc.) are bouncing.

In fact, any way to confirm if emails have even been sent would be nice to have.

In theory it uses SES, but the SES dashboard shows no activity at all even though emails are definitely getting sent.

Is this functionality available at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emails are sent by Cognito on behalf of developers so there is no way to track them at this point. We have heard this functionality request in the past and we have an item on our roadmap to expose the bounce stream to developers. I will add a +1 on your behalf to the feature.

Comment: Are there any quotas on Cognito emails?  We're starting to see that some emails just aren't going out.

Comment: No quota for developers.

Comment: How can we figure out what the problem is when emails don't get delivered?

Comment: Late to the party... I posted a question in forum
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=299574

Comment: Is there a solution by now?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Cognito has added a way to configure SES (Simple Email Service) for email identity verification, please see the [Email Settings for Amazon Cognito User Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-email.html#user-pool-email-developer) of the Amazon Cognito Developer Guide. SES has different ways of [monitoring sending activity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity.html) such as deliveries, bounces and complaints through various methods including the AWS Console, SNS notifications, email, etc.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't tell me when email verification fails or if it bounces.

Comment: I have added some more information about SES, hope this helps

Comment: Yes, but if Cognito's emails via SES are not "official" SES emails.  They don't show up in SES dashboard at all.  Do you have specific examples of this actually working?